# Function currying in React instead anonymous function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jsx, anonymous-function, currying

Is there a benefit to use function currying instead of anonymous function (in terms of efficiency) inside events callbacks (onClick for example) when we need to pass params?

```
const doSomthing = (arg1, arg2) => {
  ...
}
<div> onClick={() => doSomthing(arg1, arg2)} />

// or

const doSomthing = (arg1, arg2) => () => {
  ...
}
<div onClick={doSomthing(arg1, arg2)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will be triggered if click event occurs:

```
const doSomthing = (arg1, arg2) => {
  ...
}
<div> onClick={() => doSomthing(arg1, arg2)} />
```

The following will be triggered once the component renders which is a bad practice:

```
const doSomthing = (arg1, arg2) => () => {
  ...
}
<div onClick={doSomthing(arg1, arg2)} />
```

Comment: The second version of `doSomthing(arg1, arg2)` returns a function that wouldn't be called until the click event is fired.

Comment: both of the function wont be called until the click event fired.

Comment: Here's the prove https://codepen.io/AdamMorsi/pen/wvxBRXX?editors=1010